# How to make dots ... hyperlink in php?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a php code as shown below in which I want to make **...** **hyperlink in php**.

```
<div class="video-block__contlink">
   <p><?php echo limit_text($stream->excerpt, 240);//wp_kses_post( $stream->excerpt ) ?></p>  //Line#Z
</div>

function limit_text($text, $limit) {
if( strlen( $text ) > $limit ) {
$cut_text = substr( $text, 0, $limit );
$last_space = strrpos( $cut_text, " " );
$short_text = substr( $cut_text, 0, $last_space );
$text = $short_text." (...)";  // Line #A
}
return $text;
}
```

At this moment, it shows (...) when text limit of 240 is reached as per the above code logic at Line#Z

**Problem Statement:**

At Line#A, I want three dots ... to be made hyperlink.

Following is the href link which I want to include in three dots.

```
<a class="video-block__titlelink" href="<?php echo esc_url( $stream->permalink ) ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $stream->title ); ?></a>
```

*This is what I have tried :*

```
$url='<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $stream->permalink ) ?>">(...)</a>;
```

At **Line#A**, I have placed $url instead of (...) but it doesn't work.

`$text = $short_text.$url;`  // Line #A

Comment: `$url = '<a href="'.esc_url($stream->permalink).'">(...)</a>';`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can you explain me in an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your problem can be reduced down to this code:

```
<?php echo "<b><?php echo 'hi!' ?></b>" ?>
```

This code will not write `<b>hi</b>`, it'll write `<b><?php echo 'hi!' ?></b>` instead. The problem is that you can't nest PHP tags like that. Once you're in PHP mode, you can't enter PHP mode *again*.

The way to put strings together from inside the PHP language is to use the string join operator, which is written with the full stop (`.`)

```
<?php echo "<b>" . 'hi' . "</b>" ?>
```

This will write `<b>hi</b>` instead. Your URL problem is the same way, as @NiettheDarkAbsol mentioned:

```
$url = '<a href="' . esc_url($stream->permalink) . '">(...)</a>';
```